# MySql how to make a row and add children tables based on type with a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have three tables:

Guest can make a reservation and in the reservation table you can see what kind of reservation the guest made based on the primary key 'pID'. I dont have a 'type' row in my database. I want to show the available rooms in the hotel, so basically the pID, type and city of the luxe rooms and small rooms that dont occur in reservation. How can I do this with a IN operator?

reservation:

```
pID              |begindate    | enddate     |   
------------------------------------------------------
COD12            | 2014-07-15  | 2014-07-18  |
COD400           | 2014-07-20  | 2014-07-21  |
KOD12            | 2014-07-01  | 2014-07-07  |
COD600           | 2014-07-04  | 2014-07-12  |
MOD10            | 2014-08-10  | 2014-08-16  |
```

Luxe room table:

```
pID              |city         |    
---------------------------------
COD12            | Corona      | 
COD400           | Corona      |   
KHMED12          | Kansas      |
KHMED14          | Kansas      |
KOD12            | Kentucky    |
KOD30            | Kentucky    |
```

```
Small room table:

pID              |city         |    
---------------------------------
COD600           | Corona      |
MOD10            | Madrid      |
KOD20            | Kentucky    |
```

What I want:
L = luxe room
S = small room

```
pID              |type         | city   
-----------------------------------------
KHMED12          | L           | Kansas
KHMED14          | L           | Kansas
KOD20            | S           | Kentucky
KOD30            | L           | Kentucky
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"don't occur in" --> Think "LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL"

```
( SELECT pid, 'L' AS type, city
      FROM luxe
      LEFT JOIN reservations res USING(pid)
      WHERE res.pid IS NULL )
UNION ALL
( SELECT pid, 'S' AS type, city
      FROM small
      LEFT JOIN reservations res USING(pid)
      WHERE res.pid IS NULL )
```

You should also rethink your separation of the two 'identical' tables (small and luxe); consider combining them into a single table.  It is much easier to filter things out than to combine tables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT 
    -- pID
    res.pID,
    -- If there is a bigger count in the lux, than lux has the order, else: small has it
    IF(res.lux_count > res.small_count, "L", "S") as type,
    -- Same logic, but for getting the city from the right table by order pID
    IF(res.lux_count > res.small_count, 
        (SELECT lt.city FROM LUX_ROOM_TABLE lr WHERE lr.pID = res.pID),
        (SELECT lt.city FROM SMALL_ROOM_TABLE sr WHERE sr.pID = res.pID)) as city
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        -- Reservation ID
        r.pID,
        -- Will give 1 if contains the order, 0 if not: for Luxe
        (SELECT count(*) from LUX_ROOM_TABLE LRT where LRT.pID=R.pID) as lux_count,
        -- Will give 1 if contains the order, 0 if not: for small
        (SELECT count(*) from SMALL_ROOM_TABLE SRT where SRT.pID=R.pID) as small_count,
    FROM RESERVATIONS R
    WHERE
        -- Where ID is in the list of your orders.
        pID IN ("","")
) res;
```